# How to pass signers inside a flow in new state creation under "Event Scheduling " in Corda?

Tags: corda

I have incorporated "Event-Scheduling" functionality in one state , which when accepted will in  turn create another new state.The new state creation is triggered by Event scheduling function.I'm setting Initiator in the new state creation flow.

```
val session = initiateFlow(output.IOT)
session.send(true)
```

Also , in responder flow,I'm trying to pass signers.There as well, we are calling Initiate flow as below .

```
val sessions = listOf(SiemenParty, CustomerParty).toSet().map { party: Party -> initiateFlow(party) }.toSet()

val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, sessions, Companion.GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))"
```

I'm getting exception at CollectSignatureFlow like :

> com.template.flow.CreateIOTFlow$Acceptor, as a flow that initiates other flows, must be annotated with net.corda.core.flows.InitiatingFlow.

What am i doing wrong ? How to set signers ?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `@InitiatingFlow` annotation over your flow as result you are facing this exception. as you are using `initiateFlow`the flow must be annotated with `@InitiatingFlow` annotation

Comment: It's n't working.It's again showing exception as below:"Missing signatures for [com.template.contract.EquipmentIOTContract.Commands.Create"

Comment: I think it's working, isn't it? The error which you faced earlier seems to have done. Now you are facing something else. raise it as a separate question as per SO guidelines. also, the error you are seeing now means that the signatures are missing in the Transactions.